# how to reduce react native build apk size

Tags: android, react-native

i have built a react native project and i added some libraries and i build an apk to check if it works and i saw this. i have no activities right now, just a couple of libraries.

[image: Android Studio Analyze Apk Photo]
this is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "load-script": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.10",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "i18next": "^19.4.2",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.9.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.3.4",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-localize": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.14",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.3.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.3.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0",
    "reactotron-react-native": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

how can i reduce the apk size and is there any way to know which library is taking too much size ?

Comment: read https://www.manuelrdsg.com/2019/06/secure-your-react-native-apps-before-production/

Answer (score 1):

```
  release {
            debuggable false
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            setProguardFiles([getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'])
          }
```

- With the lines **`minifyEnabled`** and **`useProguard`**, you will
  activate the minification and obfuscation of the code.
- Libraries that you add to your code may include unused resources. Gradle can automatically remove resources on your behalf if you enable **`shrinkResources`** in your app's build.gradle file.

> /**  * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.  */
>   def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

Proguard is a tool that can slightly reduce the size of the APK. It does this by stripping parts of the React Native Java bytecode (and its dependencies) that your app is not using.

- Set **`def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true`** this would enable
  Progaurd to compress the Java Bytecode. This reduces the app size.
- Set def **`enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true`**.

Answer (score 0):

In `android/app/build.gradle` add line:

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
```

Comment: you can use Hermes engine also